# Escape several single quote and double quote

Tags: javascript

I'm in trouble trying to escape several quotes.

Here is my code :

```
var somevalue = "test";
return $("<li onclick='document.getElementById(\"AddGenre\").value = " + '\'' + somevalue + '\'' ";'><div><img src='" + item.img + "'><span>" + somevalue + "</span></div></li>").appendTo(ul);
```

I got the following error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Just don't use inline JavaScript, especially not when there's jQuery.

Comment: And you can use a function for updating the value instead of doing it inline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a `+`

```
"<li onclick='document.getElementById(\"AddGenre\").value = " + '\'' + somevalue + '\'' + ";'><div><img src='" + item.img + "'><span>" + somevalue + "</span></div></li>"
//                                                                                     ^^^
```

You should also look into [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
`<span>${myValue} and some quotes " ' "" ' '' no escapes needed</span`
```

Comment: I still get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: I don't. U'll need to provide more details.

Comment: @executable That is from a different part of the program then. Do you have a `}` at the end of your function?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wasn't totally sure what value you wanted to assign to AddGenre when someone clicks a newly added list item -- but if I was right in thinking that value should be `'test'`, this code does exactly that in a whole different way.

I started by trying to avoid the need for the nested quotes, which the main function does by adding the elements to the DOM one at a time. A couple of helper functions make it look a little cleaner.

**NOTE: Click "full-page" when running the snippet. (Otherwise, SO's console obscures a portion of the rendered DOM.)**

```js
var genresList = document.getElementById("genresList");
var AddGenre = document.getElementById("AddGenre");
appendLi("test");

console.log(genresList.outerHTML.split("><").join(">\n<"));

// Main function
function appendLi(someValue){

  // Defines elements
  const li = create("li"),
        div = create("div"),
        img = create("img"),
        span = create("span");

  // Modifies elements
  span.innerHTML = someValue;
  img.setAttribute("src","item.img");
  li.dataset.addGenre = `'${someValue}'`; // Stores value to use when li is clicked
  li.addEventListener("click", updateAddGenre); // Defines click listener
  
  // Appends elements to the DOM
  append(li, img);
  append(li, span);
  append(div, li);
  append(genresList, li);
}

// Handles clicks on added list items
function updateAddGenre(event){
  AddGenre.value = event.currentTarget.dataset.addGenre
}

// Sugar
function create(tagName){ return document.createElement(tagName); }
function append(parent, node){ parent.appendChild(node); }
```

```html
<h5>AddGenres:</h5>
<input id="AddGenre" />

<h5>Genres List:</h5>
<ul id="genresList"></ul>
```